# How to track an object to a specific property in the Blender Game Engine

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I make a game with the Blender Game Engine. I would like to make a cube (Enemy) which moves inside a navigation mesh.
This cube should follow all the objects with a specific property. The cube also should follow the nearest of this objects  in the navmesh.
I found this script. But it only work for the "Edit Object" actuator. I need this script work for the "Steering" actuator and the  path following. I hope you can help me.

```
def target_prop(cont):
self = cont.owner
objects = self.scene.objects

test = [o for o in objects if self["Cube"] in o]
test.sort(key=lambda o: self.getDistanceTo(o))

target, *_ = test

act_track, *_ = cont.actuators
act_track.object = target

for act in cont.actuators:
    cont.activate(act)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple change. The syntax for the "Steering" actuator calls for a `target` field, not a `track _object` field. So your new snippet looks like this:

```
def target_prop(cont):
self = cont.owner
objects = self.scene.objects

test = [o for o in objects if self["Cube"] in o]
test.sort(key=lambda o: self.getDistanceTo(o))

target, *_ = test

act_track, *_ = cont.actuators
act_track.target = target

for act in cont.actuators:
     cont.activate(act)
```

you can see the only change is line #11